# Access updating field to NULL value on error condition of IIF(IsError())

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to update a table in MS Access using the following query:

```
UPDATE [Stock Detail Item] 
SET [Stock Detail Item].Total_Payments =
IIF(
  IsError(DSum("Payment_Amount", "Principal Payments", "Stock_No='" & [Stock Detail Item].Stock_No & "'")),
  CCur(0),
  DSum("Payment_Amount", "Principal Payments", "Stock_No='" & [Stock Detail Item].Stock_No & "'")
);
```

When there are payments for the `Stock_No` in the `Principal Payments` table, the query correctly inserts the total payment amount into the table.

But when there are no payments in the `Principal Payments` table, the `IsError` function should return `True`, which means the `IIF` should return `0` cast to currency.

The problem is, the query is inserting `NULL` in these instances.  This is causing errors later down the line when trying to perform math to the `NULL` value.

I have tried this with and without casting `0` or `0.00` to the currency data type, with no luck.

Any idea why this returns the correct value when no error is present, and `NULL` value when there is an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You state:

> But when there are no payments in the Principal Payments table, the `IsError` function should return `True`.

However, per the [documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/dsum-function-08f8450e-3bf6-45e2-936f-386056e61a32), when no records match the given criteria or if the domain (table/query) contains no records, the [`DSum`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/dsum-function-08f8450e-3bf6-45e2-936f-386056e61a32) function will return **Null**, not an error:

> If no record satisfies the criteria argument or if domain contains no records, the `DSum` function returns a **Null**.

As such, I would suggest changing your code to the following:

```
update [Stock Detail Item] 
set [Stock Detail Item].Total_Payments = 
Nz(DSum("Payment_Amount", "Principal Payments", "Stock_No='" & [Stock Detail Item].Stock_No & "'"),0)
```

This statement makes use of the [`Nz`](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/nz-function-8ef85549-cc9c-438b-860a-7fd9f4c69b6c) function, which will return the second supplied argument (which is `0` in the above code) in the event that the first is `Null`, else the first argument (the result of `DSum`) is returned.

Alternatively, you could use the [`IsNull`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/isnull-function-f963233b-1c1e-4b0c-8bc3-3e8c0ea67c61) function in place of [`IsError`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/iserror-function-40a89200-138b-4e60-b254-34aea51b2e6b).

Comment: I went with changing it to IsNull function as there was less to change and it is easier for others to read if they aren't familiar with the Nz function.  Thanks for suggesting both solutions.